# ip rule: deleting all rules from table

Tags: linux, bash, routes

I am working on a bash script that use de `ip rule...` command to add and remove some rules. But I am having problems removing them. For example `ip rule show` output looks like this:

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32764:  from all fwmark 0x3022 lookup 12322 
32765:  from 10.10.10.1 lookup 12322 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

All the info I have is the table id (12322) and I need to remove all the rules that lookup that table.

I tried these commands: `ip rule del table 12322` and `ip rule del lookup 12322`, but both commands remove always the first rule, and not the first rule that lookup 12322, I mean the first rule `from all lookup local`. If I run any of those commands 5 times I end up with no rules.

How can I remove all the rules that `lookup 12322` in one command?

Comment: There are some work-arounds in the answers to this post, but the bottom line is this functionality is not available / not built-in to the ip command (i.e. iproute2). One must manually identify each relevant rule and remove it individually.

Answer (score 12):

You can delete using "from 0/0 to 0/0" but that will remove only ONE rule. To remove them all use something like this:

```
while ip rule delete from 0/0 to 0/0 table 12322 2>/dev/null; do true; done
```

This will delete all the rules until there are no more.

Comment: The above one-liner works for me without "from 0/0 to 0/0 "

Answer (score 5):

```
ip rule del prio {rule #}
```

Simple. It works. And it's the "official" method per Kuznetsov's original iproute2 instructions.

Also note from the iproute2 manual:

> Warning: Changes to the RPDB made with these commands do not become active
>   immediately. It is assumed that after a script nishes a batch of updates, it 
>   ushes
>   the routing cache with ip route flush cache.

To delete ALL rules, you may use the following.

```
ip route del
```

If you are connecting to the server via SSH, doing so will drop your connection and lock you out.

Comment: what if you have two rules with the same rule #: one with ```0:      from all lookup local``` and another with ```0:      from all uidrange 0-0 lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0``` but you want to keep the default lookup local rule and delete the suppress_prefixlength one?

Comment: You can't. It doesn't work like that. The rule ID numbers are unique, within the range of 0-32767.

Comment: So do you think I have an issue where I have two ```0``` IDs in my ip rule list?

Comment: @ikwyl6 Yes. You cannot have two ip rules with the same rule ID. tbh, I have never tried to do that before. I would imagine either the first is applied and subsequent attempts are either overwritten or ignored. A third possibility is ip might auto-increment your rule ID, but I doubt it. Either way, you'd have to experiment to figure out what is going on, or review the code. Experimenting is likely quicker and would provide you with a clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

Does the following work?

```
ip rule delete from 0/0 to 0/0 table 12322
```

Comment: @Si289 My problem seems to be a bug on iproute.

Answer (score 1):

To delete all the rules of a table, you can flush it :

```
ip rule flush table 12322
```

Comment: `ip rule flush` has no arguments and deletes every nonzero-priority rule, including `32766: from all lookup main`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a bug on iproute:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/linux.debian.bugs.dist/wPaWWfa3K0Q/lCIOfpxsFgAJ

I am now using something like `ip rule show | grep "regex" | xargs -r -L1 ip rule del` which seems to work fine.